# My tabularx gives error, "Missing number, treated as zero"

Tags: tabularx

```
\begin{table*}[h!]  
    \caption{list of unique effects on project plan with their descriptions}
    \label{tab:defination}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \centering 
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X|X}
            \noindent
            \begin{tabular}{
                    |p{\dimexpr.10\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% column 1
                    |p{\dimexpr.26\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% column 2
                    |p{\dimexpr.65\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% column 3
                }
                \hline
                No & Effects  & Descriptions \\
                \hline
                1 & Project priority (EFF1) & Change in dependency of task and project  milestone due to redirection, reallocation and prioritization of project scope resulting change in project priority. Thus change activities in the critical path and slips the  project schedule  \\ 
                \hline 
                2 & Lack of motivation and direction (EFF2) & Difference in individual's perception, culture and scope cross cutting (De-scoping of feature) leads to decrease in staff motivation and unmeet project deadlines.\\
                \hline 
                3 & Increase cost (EFF3) & Change in life cycle costing, unapproved scope, risk mitigation, initial estimates and adding more decision points increase project cost and reduce contingency reserved.\\
                \hline 
                4 & Project resources change (EFF4) & Change in project resources (team member, project manager, hardware, software) with limited boundaries of the project leads to the scope issues and increases overhead for potential delays and budget.\\
                \hline 
                5 & Project risks (EFF5) & Technological uncertainty, untried assumption constrains, requirement uncertainty and volatility (have impact on project risk management) can direct blowout cost afterwards.\\
                \hline
                6 & Rework (EFF6) & Redefining new process, methodology, strategy, policy, alternatives and assessments can cause impact through rework, resulting in budget and schedule overrun.\\
                \hline
                7 & Schedule delays (EFF7) & Number of breaks, waiting periods, third party tool provider, vague scope definition, ineffective or immature process contribute towards lengthy lead time. \\ 

                \hline
                8 & Communication and coordination gaps (EFF8) & Unrealistic scope changes, trust issues, in-appropriate sharing of document and
                lack of decision making have an effect on non-technical issues like communication gaps.  \\
                \hline
                9 & Quality issue(EFF9) & Quality attributes (performance, security, reliability, availability etc.), requirement volatility (code quality, quality of project management and developer's capability) and lack of commitment have an effect on project quality, as it decreases market share and brand value.\\
                \hline
                10 & Lower productivity  (EFF10) & Workforce experience and forecasted completion date of the project has an effect on actual productivity. During project, increase in workforce size and process losses progressively decrease actual productivity. \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{tabularx}
        %\label{table1:nonlin}
    }
\end{table*}
```

gives error missing number treated as zero }.

Comment: Why are you nesting a tabular inside the tabularx and the tabularx inside a resizebox?

Comment: never put tables in `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{` it just produces inconsistent font sizes (as well as if you have a linebreak after `{` a sprurious space on the left). If you want help with an error please provide a complete but small test file, no one can run your fragment as posted but remove the inner `tabular` a s currently everything is in a one-row one column tabularx

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The posted code (if completed to a document) does not give the error in the title, it runs without error but with the warning

```
LaTeX Warning: `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.
```

However it is a one-row one column table with a nested table in that cell

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htp]  
    \caption{list of unique effects on project plan with their descriptions}
    \label{tab:defination}
\small
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|>{\raggedright}p{3cm}|X}
                \hline
                No & Effects  & Descriptions \\
                \hline
                1 & Project priority (EFF1) & Change in dependency of task and project  milestone due to redirection, reallocation and prioritization of project scope resulting change in project priority. Thus change activities in the critical path and slips the  project schedule  \\ 
                \hline 
                2 & Lack of motivation and direction (EFF2) & Difference in individual's perception, culture and scope cross cutting (De-scoping of feature) leads to decrease in staff motivation and unmeet project deadlines.\\
                \hline 
                3 & Increase cost (EFF3) & Change in life cycle costing, unapproved scope, risk mitigation, initial estimates and adding more decision points increase project cost and reduce contingency reserved.\\
                \hline 
                4 & Project resources change (EFF4) & Change in project resources (team member, project manager, hardware, software) with limited boundaries of the project leads to the scope issues and increases overhead for potential delays and budget.\\
                \hline 
                5 & Project risks (EFF5) & Technological uncertainty, untried assumption constrains, requirement uncertainty and volatility (have impact on project risk management) can direct blowout cost afterwards.\\
                \hline
                6 & Rework (EFF6) & Redefining new process, methodology, strategy, policy, alternatives and assessments can cause impact through rework, resulting in budget and schedule overrun.\\
                \hline
                7 & Schedule delays (EFF7) & Number of breaks, waiting periods, third party tool provider, vague scope definition, ineffective or immature process contribute towards lengthy lead time. \\ 

                \hline
                8 & Communication and coordination gaps (EFF8) & Unrealistic scope changes, trust issues, in-appropriate sharing of document and
                lack of decision making have an effect on non-technical issues like communication gaps.  \\
                \hline
                9 & Quality issue(EFF9) & Quality attributes (performance, security, reliability, availability etc.), requirement volatility (code quality, quality of project management and developer's capability) and lack of commitment have an effect on project quality, as it decreases market share and brand value.\\
                \hline
                10 & Lower productivity  (EFF10) & Workforce experience and forecasted completion date of the project has an effect on actual productivity. During project, increase in workforce size and process losses progressively decrease actual productivity. \\
                \hline
        \end{tabularx}

\end{table*}
\end{document}
```